# How to store an embedded map in OrientDB with document api?

Tags: orientdb

I tried:

```
Map<String, ODocument> myEntries = new HashMap<>();
//fill the map
...
doc.field("mymap", myEntries, OType.EMBEDDEDMAP);
```

but it gives me:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.OTrackedMap cannot be cast to java.util.List

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used OrientDb 2.1.11 and it works

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(path);
db.open("root","root");

Map<String, Object> myEntries = new HashMap<String, Object>();
myEntries.put("key1",1);
myEntries.put("key2",2);
myEntries.put("key3",3);

ODocument doc = new ODocument("Test");
doc.field("mymap", myEntries, OType.EMBEDDEDMAP);
doc.save();
```

FROM STUDIO

[image]

Comment: it's all ok with orientdb, it was my fault somewhere